# Change default user folders path?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, default

In previous releases of Ubuntu, I used Ubuntu Tweak to change the paths to the user folders (Music, Documents, Videos, etc). I can't find an option in Gnome 3 to do this, and Ubuntu Tweak's ppa still has no version for Oneiric.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Open a terminal and write this command:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Each row is a user folder definition (music, video...), edit as you want. For example, I did not want the videos folder in home, but in a separate disk, and changed the XDG_VIDEOS_DIR parameter this way:

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/media/share/Video"
```

**OR** simply run:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set VIDEOS "/media/share/Video"
```

Logout and login back to effect properly.

Comment: To make it effective immediately, run `xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Comment: after i restart or unplug my external disk the folders disappear from that list. any idea how to solve that? http://askubuntu.com/questions/251624/set-default-folders-to-external-hdd-permanently

Comment: From the manual for `xdg-user-dirs-update` I'm guessing that it goes back to the default directories if they exist, so just delete them and it should be good

Comment: @ArthurSpoon Unfortunately, no, this (e.g. deleting ~/Documents) doesn't stop the overwriting of the tweaked user-dirs.dirs file.

Answer (score 4):

As at today (7 years later!), my experiments seem to show:

1. These variables are set in the file `~/.config/user-dir.dirs` relate to
   XDG, which stands for "X Desktop Group"... i.e. they appear to
   relate to the "windowing" processes.  But for example, none of these
   variables are then accessible by the user (or root) as an environment
   variable
2. It appears that the variable `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR` is the one which is
   responsible, in Nemo, for giving one particular directory a
   "special" icon
3. That's what we're all bothered about: how to give one particular
   directory a special icon all to itself, signifying "this is your
   DOCUMENTS directory"
4. To give this to a particular directory other than `~/Documents`,
    
   -- a. make a link from the directory you want under "My Computer" in the LH panel of Nemo
   -- b. change the value of the `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR` variable in `~/.config/user-dir.dirs` to this directory, using an absolute path.
   -- c. log out and back in: whatever its name may be, in both the LH and RH side of Nemo your directory should now have the "special" DOCUMENTS icon!

NB it is not sufficient, as suggested in a comment above, simply to delete the `~/Documents` directory for everything to work OK.  Bear in mind in particular that, if at startup it is found that the  `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR` path actually doesn't lead to a valid directory, the setting for `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR` will be overwritten in `user-dir.dirs`, replacing it, in principle, with `$HOME/Documents`... (in fact, oddly, my experiments seem to find that it is usually replaced with `$HOME`, for some inexplicable reason).

NB2 as an alternative to the above (especially if the "special" icon doesn't matter in particular to you), you could use a symlink ... which you can call "Documents".  In fact, you could have both: a symlink and a special icon for your target file.

NB3 I don't believe you can make a symlink as suggested  ... AND give it a special `DOCUMENTS` icon! But given this, all seems to be about cosmetics anyway maybe it, um, doesn't matter much!

Comment: Please format you post regarding to this link: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

You can still install Ubuntu Tweak and do it with that, if you dont want to mess around with the terminal.