# 17.10 personal folder location

Tags: directory

I have Ubuntu installed and running fine on my 500gb SSD and I want to set up my second hard drive. But I don't just want a new location in my file manager (nemo) I want to set the hard drive location to `/home/$USER/Videos`
that way when I go to that location and open it the hard drive with all my media on it opens. the second hard drive is NTFS for the moment but that can change if necessary, it doesn't have to be visible to windows but I would prefer it if possible.

I've looked into several things including Ubuntu tweak but it inst around for 17.10 and also this [Change default user folders path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67044/change-default-user-folders-path)

Comment: The question you linked is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I mount a 2nd disk with the following line in `/etc/fstab`: (Note: Your `UUID=` value Will Be Different - use `lsblk --output="NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID"`)

```
UUID=362254e8-2b99-442d-8ad9-4a348bc08032 /home/w3/mnt/SP ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,noauto,user,rw 0 0
```

I have to use the `noauto`, and issue `mount ~/mnt/SP` after login, because I have an encrypted `$HOME`, and `/home/w3/mnt/SP` does not exist earlier.

I also don't want the disk mounted at all times. Since you do, you could put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $(mountpoint -q $HOME/Videos; echo $?) != 0 ]] ; 
then
    mount $HOME/Videos
fi
```

Comment: i take it the "home/w3/mnt/SP" part of the line is the location of my drive so for me it would be /media/user/Library as the hdd is called library of  or is that the location of where i want to mount it ie /home/user/Videos

Comment: also are the "nodev,nosuid,noexec,noauto,user,rw 0 0" settings ok with an NTFS hdd your example uses ext4

Comment: lsblk --output="NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID returns      
 sdb                                           
├─sdb1                                        
└─sdb2 ntfs     /media/user/Library Library  9A14124414122433

Comment: do i just not add noauto???

Comment: what are nodev,nosuid,noexec,noauto,user what am i setting when i do this??

Comment: They are reasons for you to read manpages: `man mount;man fstab

Answer (score 0):

OK guys and gals hear goes. I'm not good at these so bear with.

- open terminal and enter (thank to waltinator for the command)

  ```
  lsblk --output="NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID"
  ```
- this gave my harddrive id `9A14124414122433`
- run command (just in case)

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
  ```
- edit fstab and add

  ```
  UUID=9A14124414122433 /media/Videos ntfs defaults 0 0
  ```
- deleted my /home/user/Videos folder and rebooted
- run command

  ```
  rm -rf ~/Videos && ln -s /media/Videos ~/Videos
  ```