# add a folder on left panel in nautilus permanently

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and in my nautilus file manager, I want to add Desktop to my left panel. I tried using Ctrl + D method and it adds the Desktop on the left panel. This is basically adding Desktop as a bookmark. I can remove this Desktop by right clicking. But when I right click on already present folders in the panel(like Home or Downloads), the remove option is greyed out.
How can I add Desktop to the left panel permanently and not as a bookmark.

Thanks

Comment: You can't unless you edit the Gnome's User folders: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050409/1210606

Answer (score 2):

Step-1: open the file manager
Step-2: drag "Desktop" to the sidebar
Step-3: Sidebar will show a "New Bookmark" option and drop it there.

It is done.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP ~/Desktop
```

to set the special status of your ~/Desktop folder, after which it will appear in the left pane.

Comment: I did that, but nothing happened. May be I need to restart the system?

Comment: I tested this answer myself. This will work only if your "Desktop" folder exists in your home directory. Alternatively, you can edit ~/.config/user-dirs.dir manually. That it does not work leads me to suspect that your Desktop folder is in a different location, or is named differently.